# Create a pathfinder using A* on big terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I try to implement this tutorial of pathfinding using A* and I add a dimension to make it 3d -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cq5Umv3pMC9SPnKjfp9eGW&index=1

my problem is that I have a really big terrain(10km on 10km) with drones(this is why I need a 3d path finder) and a grid on all my map is really heavy so I try to create a "local" grid for every seeker and to do that I first create a "sphere" for every seeker and the I find the closest point on the sphere to the target like that:
[image]

my problem now is to make my grid personal per every seeker, I try to add a instance of my sphere seeker component and then to change to position of the grid to the seeker position but when I do it, the target position is changed.

this is my grid script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
        
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
            
using UnityEngine;
            
public class GridManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[Header("Players")]
[SerializeField] SpherePlayer player;

[Header("General")]
public Vector3 gridWorldSize;
public float nodeRadius;
public TerrainType[] walkableRegions;
public int obsticleProximityPenalty = 10;
[Header("Layer Masks")]
public LayerMask unwalkableMask;
LayerMask walkableMask;
Dictionary<int, int> walkableRegionsDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
Node[,,] grid;

int penaltyMin = int.MaxValue;
int penaltyMax = int.MinValue;
float nodeDiameter;
int gridSizeX, gridSizeY, gridSizeZ;
public List<Node> path;
[SerializeField] bool onlyPathGizmo = true;

public int MaxSize { get { return gridSizeX * gridSizeY * gridSizeZ; } }

private void Awake()
{
    nodeDiameter = nodeRadius * 2;
    gridSizeX = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridWorldSize.x / nodeDiameter);
    gridSizeY = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridWorldSize.y / nodeDiameter);
    gridSizeZ = Mathf.RoundToInt(gridWorldSize.z / nodeDiameter);
    foreach (TerrainType region in walkableRegions)
    {
        walkableMask.value |= region.terrainMask.value;
        walkableRegionsDictionary.Add((int)Mathf.Log(region.terrainMask.value, 2), region.terrainPenalty);
    }
    CreateGrid();

}
private void CreateGrid()
{
    grid = new Node[gridSizeX, gridSizeY, gridSizeZ];
    Vector3 worldBottomLeft = player.transform.position - Vector3.right * gridWorldSize.x / 2 - Vector3.forward * gridWorldSize.y / 2;

    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < gridSizeZ; z++)
            {
                Vector3 worldPoint = worldBottomLeft +
                    Vector3.right * (x * nodeDiameter + nodeRadius) +
                    Vector3.forward * (y * nodeDiameter + nodeRadius) +
                    Vector3.up * (z * nodeDiameter + nodeRadius);

                bool walkable = !(Physics.CheckSphere(worldPoint, nodeRadius, unwalkableMask));
                int movementPenalty = 0;

                //raycast

                Ray ray = new Ray(worldPoint + Vector3.up * 50, Vector3.down);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit, 100, walkableMask))
                {
                    walkableRegionsDictionary.TryGetValue(hit.collider.gameObject.layer, out movementPenalty);
                }
                if (!walkable) movementPenalty += obsticleProximityPenalty;

                grid[x, y,z] = new Node(walkable, worldPoint, x, y,z, movementPenalty);
            }
            
        }
    }
    //BlurPenaltyMap(3);
}

private void BlurPenaltyMap(int blurSize)
{
    int kernelSize = blurSize * 2 + 1;
    int kernelExtents = (kernelSize - 1) / 2;
    int[,] penaltiesHorizontalPass = new int[gridSizeX, gridSizeY];
    int[,] penaltiesVerticalPass = new int[gridSizeX, gridSizeY];

    //depth pass

    //horizontal pass
    for (int y = 0; y < gridSizeY; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -kernelExtents; x <= kernelExtents; x++)
        {
            int sampleX = Mathf.Clamp(x, 0, kernelExtents);
            penaltiesHorizontalPass[0, y] += grid[sampleX, y,0].movementPenalty;
        }
        for (int x = 1; x < gridSizeX; x++)
        {
            int removeIndex = Mathf.Clamp(x - kernelExtents - 1, 0, gridSizeX);
            int addIndex = Mathf.Clamp(x + kernelExtents - 1, 0, gridSizeX - 1);
            penaltiesHorizontalPass[x, y] = penaltiesHorizontalPass[x - 1, y] - grid[removeIndex, y,0].movementPenalty + grid[addIndex, y,0].movementPenalty;
        }
    }

    //vertical pass
    for (int x = 0; x < gridSizeX; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -kernelExtents; y <= kernelExtents; y++)
        {
            int sampleY = Mathf.Clamp(y, 0, kernelExtents);
            penaltiesVerticalPass[x, 0] += penaltiesHorizontalPass[x, sampleY];
        }

        //edge case
        int blurredPenalty = Mathf.RoundToInt((float)penaltiesVerticalPass[x, 0] / (kernelSize * kernelSize));
        grid[x, 0,0].movementPenalty = blurredPenalty;


        for (int y = 1; y < gridSizeY; y++)
        {
            int removeIndex = Mathf.Clamp(y - kernelExtents - 1, 0, gridSizeY);
            int addIndex = Mathf.Clamp(y + kernelExtents - 1, 0, gridSizeY - 1);
            penaltiesVerticalPass[x, y] = penaltiesVerticalPass[x, y - 1] - penaltiesHorizontalPass[x, removeIndex] + penaltiesHorizontalPass[x, addIndex];

            blurredPenalty = Mathf.RoundToInt((float)penaltiesVerticalPass[x, y] / (kernelSize * kernelSize));
            grid[x, y,0].movementPenalty = blurredPenalty;

            if (blurredPenalty > penaltyMax) penaltyMax = blurredPenalty;
            if (blurredPenalty < penaltyMin) penaltyMin = blurredPenalty;
        }
    }
}

public List<Node> GetNeighbours(Node node)
{
    List<Node> result = new List<Node>();

    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
    {
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            for (int z = -1; z <=1; z++)
            {
                if (x == 0 && y == 0 && z==0) continue;

                int checkX = node.gridX + x;
                int checkY = node.gridY + y;
                int checkZ = node.gridZ + z;
                if (checkX >= 0 && checkX < gridSizeX && 
                    checkY >= 0 && checkY < gridSizeY && 
                        checkZ >= 0 && checkZ < gridSizeZ)
                    result.Add(grid[checkX, checkY,checkZ]);
            }
            
        }
    }


    return result;
}

public Node NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPosition)
{

    float perX = (worldPosition.x + gridWorldSize.x / 2) / gridWorldSize.x;
    float perY = (worldPosition.z + gridWorldSize.y / 2) / gridWorldSize.y;
    float perZ = (worldPosition.y + gridWorldSize.z / 2) / gridWorldSize.z;

    perX = Mathf.Clamp01(perX);
    perY = Mathf.Clamp01(perY);
    perZ = Mathf.Clamp01(perZ);

    int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeX - 1) * perX);
    int y = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeY - 1) * perY);
    int z = Mathf.RoundToInt((gridSizeZ - 1) * perZ);
    return grid[x, y, z];
}
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(player.transform.position, new Vector3(gridWorldSize.x, 1, gridWorldSize.y));
    if (grid != null)
    {

        foreach (Node node in grid)
        {
            if (onlyPathGizmo)
            {
                if (path != null && path.Contains(node))
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
                    Gizmos.DrawCube(node.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter - .2f));

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.Lerp(Color.white, Color.black, Mathf.InverseLerp(penaltyMin, penaltyMax, node.movementPenalty));
                Gizmos.color = node.walkable ? Gizmos.color : Color.red;
                if (path != null && path.Contains(node))
                {
                    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;

                }
                Gizmos.DrawCube(node.worldPosition, Vector3.one * (nodeDiameter - .2f));
            }
        }

    }
}
[Serializable]
public class TerrainType
{
    public LayerMask terrainMask;


       public int terrainPenalty;
    }
}
```

I hope that I explain myself well, thanks.

Comment: Please *format* your code. This is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, it's better now?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. I don't see where any positions are changed in the above code - only changing penalties.